# Forcing yAxis.max is not respected in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, max, axis

...or what is my fault?

I am trying to set the yAxis.max values on both axis. But it doesn't work.

The left yAxis should go from 330-410 with a tickInterval of 10, the right one from -0.6-1,1 with a tickInterval of 0.1.

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/9hnx0w46/2/).

```
   yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: "#4553c5"
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: "ppm",
            align: "high",
            rotation: 0,
            x: 10,
            y: -30,
            textAlign: 'left',
            style: {
                color: "#4553c5"
            }
        },
        min: 330,
        max: 410,
        tickInterval: 10,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: '#efefef',
        endOnTick: false
    }, {
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: "#ec5d61"
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: "°C Anomaly",
            align: "high",
            rotation: 0,
            textAlign: "right",
            x: -10,
            y: -30,
            style: {
                color: "#ec5d61"
            }
        },
        min: -0.6,
        max: 1.1,
        tickInterval: 0.2,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: '#efefef',
        opposite: true,
        endOnTick: false
    }],
```

What is wrong with it? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a dual axis, min and max get confounded by the default `alignTicks` setting.

Setting `alignTicks` to false will usually fix the problem

```
    chart: { 
        alignTicks: false
    },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9hnx0w46/6/

OTOH, using a dual y-axis chart like this is generally a bad idea, as it confounds two series whose interactions don't mean anything, since they are being measured on two different scales.

Useful read on the subject:

- https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business.../dual-scaled_axes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When you use multiple yAxis, `min` and `max` values usually *calculated* by HighCharts and these calculated values overrides your settings.

The trick is using `tickAmount`, `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` together.

Here is the solution of your problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hnx0w46/4/)